# Find a global maximum and show that it is unique

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima, global-optimization

> Let $a_{i}  \in \mathbb R_{>0}$ and consider the following problem:
>
> $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & f(x) := \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n}  x_{i}^{a_{i}}\\ \text{subject to} & x \in S\end{array}$$
>
> where $S$ is a convex set. Find a global maximum and show that it is unique.

It is an unconstrained problem. I have calculated its first order and second order derivative but I am not concluding a perfect solution.

Comment: Convex set where? This function is not even defined when $x_i$ is negative and $a_i$ is a fraction.

Comment: what is the set $S$?

Comment: How is it unconstrained if it's over $S$?

Comment: This is going to be mostly dependent on $S$

Comment: I am not having an idea how it is related to a convex set.

Comment: where do you get the question from? may we know the source?